# Running the coded more than once deletes the relevant data

Tags: excel, vba

I have code with a BIG weakness.  If i run it more than once it deletes the required data because it's deleting the columns as required.  The first execution formats a SAP report which runs prefectly. I don't know how to stop it deleting the columns if its run again. please can someone take a look and advise?  Thanks

```
Sub Format_ZM27KG()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim X1 As Long
    Dim LookUpTable1 As Variant
    Dim LookUpValue1 As Long
    Dim LastRow1 As Long
    Dim vAnswer1 As String
    Dim X2 As Long
    Dim vAnswer2 As Long
    Dim LastRow2 As Long
    Dim vAnswer3 As Long

    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Format KG")
    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("LookUp")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim A1 As Long
    For A1 = 1 To 8 Step 1
    ws1.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next A1

    Dim LR3 As Long
    Dim i2 As Long
    With ws1
        LR3 = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i2 = LR3 To 2 Step -1
        If Not IsNumeric(.Range("C" & i2).Value) Or .Range("C" & i2).Value = "" Then .Rows(i2).Delete
        Next i2
    End With

    'Delete columns on tab format cases
    ws1.Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.Delete
    ws1.Columns("B:D").EntireColumn.Delete
    ws1.Columns("C:M").EntireColumn.Delete
    ws1.Columns("N").EntireColumn.Delete
    ws1.Columns("C").EntireColumn.Delete

    ws1.Cells(1, "N").Value = "Category"

    LastRow1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    On Error Resume Next
    LookUpTable1 = ws2.Range("A1:C500")
    For X1 = 2 To LastRow1
    LookUpValue1 = Cells(X1, "A").Value
    vAnswer1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(LookUpValue1, LookUpTable1, 3, False)
    ws1.Cells(X1, "N").Value = vAnswer1
    Next X1

    ws1.Columns("A:AL").AutoFit

    ws1.Rows(1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

    ws1.Range("A1").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It works when i place the IF function below the line - Application.ScreenUpdating = False - .  Placing it has shown in your reply wasn't working.  Please let me know if this is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want columns to be deleted you will need to add if-statements to check whether the columns actually need to be deleted.
You can do this by changing this from your code:

```
'Delete columns on tab format cases
ws1.Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.Delete
ws1.Columns("B:D").EntireColumn.Delete
ws1.Columns("C:M").EntireColumn.Delete
ws1.Columns("N").EntireColumn.Delete
ws1.Columns("C").EntireColumn.Delete
```

Replace that with the block below:

```
'Delete columns if the column header for column "N" is not "category". 
If ws1.Cells(1, "N").Value <> "Category" then 
    ws1.Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.Delete
    ws1.Columns("B:D").EntireColumn.Delete
    ws1.Columns("C:M").EntireColumn.Delete
    ws1.Columns("N").EntireColumn.Delete
    ws1.Columns("C").EntireColumn.Delete
end if
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  When i run the macro after the initial execution, it is still deleting columns

Comment: It works when i place the IF function below the line - Application.ScreenUpdating = False - . Placing it has shown in your reply wasn't working. Please let me know if this is correct?

Comment: You can place the if block anywhere after the line`Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Format KG")`